# Writing Webpage Textbox information to a text file

Tags: javascript, html

I have this simple website[image]

Where I would like the user to enter his email in the textbox with the "someone@example.com" placeholder, and upon pressing on the Email checkbox, I would like to store his email in a text file for web development. What I made was this:

```
<input type="textbox" placeholder="someone@example.com" id="email"/>
<input type="checkbox" OnClick="develop(email)" value="done" />Email</br>
```

and the function I made with Javascript was:

```
function develop(stored)
        {
            var file = "bank.txt"; // Where I want to store the info
            store1 = document.getElementById(email);
            writeTextFile(file, store1.innerHtml());
        }
```

This, however, didn't work. What Am I doing wrong and What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

accessing files on the client side is not permitted unless it was uploaded by the user.

take a look at the following link to see how client side file access works.

[Local file access with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

you may like to use cookies to store the data if you like to use it on the client side:

[How to use JavaScript Cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)